# How to capture a variably-long, comma-seperated list of strings via Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm using `ruby 2.0` and its regex engine.

Given the following string:

```
str = "one: two, three: four"
```

The list's length is variable (from 0 to infinite). How do I capture it's entries? So in this example the regex should match:

```
[1]:"one: two", [2]:"three: four"
```

This is what I came up with so far:

```
/((\w+:\s\w+),?)*/
```

but it only gives me:

```
 => #<MatchData "one: two," 1:"one: two," 2:"one: two">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that doesn't work, sorry!

Comment: Any particular reason that you don't want to use a CSV parser for this?

Comment: The `infinite` case is a toughie.

Comment: yes, this is part of a bigger regex!

Comment: I think you could have quite varied solutions based upon what you want to do with the data.  If you'd just trying to count the tokens, that's different than acting on them.  The size of the string is important for deciding if the solution needs a managed buffer

Comment: If you want better answers I think you will have to clarify your question.  Suppose you have a method def `doit(str)` that does what you want.  What does `doit("one: two, three: four") =>` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regular expression. Use [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split):

```
str = "one: two, three: four"
str.split(', ') # => ["one: two", "three: four"]
```

---

Using regular expression:

```
str.split(/, /) # => ["one: two", "three: four"]

str.scan(/[^,]+/) # => ["one: two", " three: four"]
str.scan(/[^,]+/).map &:strip # => ["one: two", "three: four"]
```

Comment: I know that would be easier, but it's part of a larger regular expression, so I need it that way!

Comment: the scan thing is correct, but I think it's not possible to do it just with regular expressions :(( thank you anyway!

Comment: @le_me, Could you post the code that use the regular expression?

Comment: @le_me, I don't think it's possible with single regular expression to get what you want. How about [this](http://ideone.com/uJQOim) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use this regex:

```
/[^,]*/
```

**Demo:** http://www.rubular.com/r/wB6uWFxgAg

Comment: that only gives me  => #<MatchData "one: two">, ruby 2.0

Comment: You probably need `.scan(regex)` see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643658/regexp-how-to-get-every-group-of-matchdata

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the * to repeat capture parenthesis as you try to do. It will only capture the last match.

As already been pointed out, the scan method is the way to go.

```
str.scan(/(\w+:\s\w+),?/)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than that: This does what you want - ie captures the two name:value pairs in groups 1 and 2:

```
/(\w+:\s\w+)/
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Ds46idPA8C) on rubular of this regex working with your example.